# Some convenient way to transform time series into stationary one

Tags: time-series, stationarity, lstm, data-preprocessing

In [this Machine Learning Mastery post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/) we read that in order to predict time series using LSTM network, it is good to make the data stationary first and then scale it to the interval $(-1, 1).$

In order to scale the data, we can just apply `MinMaxScaler` from `sklearn.preprocessing`.

However, in order to make the data stationary Jason Brownle writes its own functions.

**Question.** Does `sklearn` provide a tool to transform the data into the stationary one? If no, maybe there are other packages which do it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic tool that turns non-stationary data into stationary. You need to understand the underlying process to do this. However, in many cases a simple trick like differencing, possibly, multiple differencing does seem to work. Sometime, log differencing works better. That is why often people don't think too much and difference the series, and so could you. It saves from thinking about the phenomenon and designing a thoughtful approach, which is always a hassle